# adjacent_vertices form igraph not working on incoming ties?

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

using the option "in" on `adjacent_vertices` from `igraph` package does give an output for vertice 5 even though it should have 1,2,3,4 listed.

```
g <- make_graph(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6), directed = T)
adjacent_vertices(g, v= c(5), mode = "in")

# output 
[[1]]
+ 0/6 vertices, from 3aecb67:
```

for an undirected graph it however works:

```
g <- make_graph("Zachary")
adjacent_vertices(g, c(1, 34))

# output 
[[1]]
+ 16/34 vertices, from 4414f0d:
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 18 20 22 32

[[2]]
+ 17/34 vertices, from 4414f0d:
 [1]  9 10 14 15 16 19 20 21 23 24 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
```

why is this? What other ways are there to identify all vertices in a sequence of incoming ties?

Comment: If you run `E(g)` you will see that vertex 5 has no incoming ties. This is what you specified in the `make_graph` call. If you run `make_graph(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6), directed = T)` you will see that one incoming tie is found for vertex 5 (from vertex 4)

Comment: mmh my bad. thank you